# sql open query on active directory with multiple where clause

Tags: mysql, ldap, adsi, openquery

I'm trying to limit the results using more than one WHERE clause like it is done in .net such as

> search.Filter = ("(&(objectCategory=person)(physicaldeliveryofficename=*))

but in SQL with open query on linked server I have this and works fine with only one where clause.

> SELECT Name, Department, Title, Telephonenumber Phone, physicaldeliveryofficename Location
>   FROM OPENQUERY( ADSI, 
>     'SELECT Name, Department, Title, Telephonenumber, physicaldeliveryofficename, SN, ST
>     FROM ''LDAP://OU=XM,DC=nix,DC=com''
>     WHERE physicaldeliveryofficename= ''*'' ')

Is it even possible to have more than one WHERE clause? Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: `OPENQUERY()` is a MS SQL Server function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More than one WHERE clause?
Or you just want to put the filters together with "AND"?

```
WHERE 
    physicaldeliveryofficename= "*" AND
    objectCategory="person"
```

Comment: I figured it out in SQL openquery it doesn't like double quotes(" ") instead I used single (' '  ' ') and it worked perfectly. And yes baldpate I was trying to but more filters together.